# SKNode alpha not copied on [node copy]

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

In my sprite kit project I am trying to duplicate a node and its children however it seems upon using [SKNode copy] all alpha properties set previously are lost, this is inclusive of all child nodes.

Is there an elegant way to duplicate the alpha properties along with nodes?

edit:
this is my work around that works for my project and hopefully will help others, however I wouldn't call it a complete answer so i'll leave the question open.

I have created an array called "alphaNames" with the names of the nodes I have change alpha values and an array called "alphaValues" with the corresponding values, then implemented the following code prior to adding to using the copied node.

```
for (NSString *nodeName in alphaNames) {
     NSString *searchString = @"//";
     SKNode *alphaNode = [copiedNode childNodeWithName:[searchString stringByAppendingString:nodeName]];
     alphaNode.alpha = [[alphaValues objectAtIndex:[alphaNames indexOfObject:nodeName]] floatValue];
}
```

This searches the entire tree under the copied node for nodes with names in the alphaNames array then applies the appropriate alpha value to it.

Comment: What do you mean with `all alpha properties`?

Comment: The alpha property for node copied and children of that node.